# How to solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Could any one help me fix this Exception error?Thanks in advance.

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:13)
```

error pointing at this line:

```
String str2 = str + (toCharArray[toCharArray.length] + String.valueOf(i));
```

java code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.TimeZone;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //System.out.println("Hello World");
        char[] toCharArray = String.valueOf((Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("utc")).getTimeInMillis() + 1825) ^ 16842788).toCharArray();
        String str = "";
        //String str2 = "";
        int i = 0;
        while (i < toCharArray.length) {
            String str2 = str + (toCharArray[toCharArray.length] + String.valueOf(i));
            i++;
            str = str2;
        }

        System.out.println("value of str:");
        System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you change the error line to   String str2 = str + (toCharArray[toCharArray.length-1] + String.valueOf(i));   exception will go away. But the answer will be all digits (if that is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

The Index of an array is 0 based. You are trying to access an element that does not exist. If you want to get the last element, you should do it as shown below.

toCharArray[toCharArray.length - 1]

Comment: Thanks for replies . I tried using toCharArray[toCharArray.length - 1] but still same error! should i declare the str2 as string outside while loop ?

Comment: I ran the code after changing to CharArray[toCharArray.length - 1]  and it worked fine. Did you recompile after changing the code ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the index you want to use in loop is i and not toCharArray.

toCharArray[toCharArray.length] will always throw an exception because the range of the array goes from 0 to length-1.